# How to make an encoding dict from password

Tags: python, dictionary, passwords, encoder, decoder

I am trying to make an encoder that does not have a predefined encoding/decoding dictionary in Python.
My plan is that it would use the string library to get all the things, then shuffle the dictionary of encoding/decoding using the random library by using a string as a password. Also, I have to make sure that it would output the same dictionary every time... I really don't know how to do that. Can you help me?

Summary:
Making An Encoder That Randomly Shuffles A Dictionary Using A Seed That Is Generated By A Password.

Example:
If I Enter This Password: "ABC",
This Should Output (Should Not Be Exactly This)
{
"a": "6",
"b": "9",
"c": "z",
"d": "a"
}
And So On...

This Can Shuffle The Dict But Not Create A Dict...

```
import random

def shuffle_dict(password):
    # Create a dictionary with keys and values
    my_dict = {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3", "d": "4"}

    # Convert the password string to a list of characters
    password_list = list(password)

    # Shuffle the list of characters using the password as a seed
    random.seed(password)
    random.shuffle(password_list)

    # Create a new dictionary with shuffled values
    shuffled_dict = {}
    for i, key in enumerate(my_dict.keys()):
        shuffled_dict[key] = password_list[i]

    return shuffled_dict

# Example usage
password = "HEFNJGBADI"
shuffled_dict = shuffle_dict(password)
print(shuffled_dict)
```

Comment: Without providing us exactly what you have and what you want to achieve, and your attempts to do so, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure exactly what you mean by this but ill give it my best shot!

You could append the strings into the dictionary as long as you have a header for each one

```
my_dict = {"FirstString":[],"SecondString":[],"ThirdString":[]};

my_dict["FirstString"].append(String1)
my_dict["SecondString"].append(String2)
my_dict["ThirdString"].append(String3)  

print(my_dict)
```

The "String1" "String2" or "String3" can be either preset strings or as I am assuming you need, a variable from the library.

Comment: It would be advisable to have an example of what the `print` line will actually print

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I  Have Added Some Examples And A Summary To The Question. I Understand That My Question Can Be Unclear.